# Read a txt-file as dict containing a numpy-array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a lot of .txt files that I want to read. 
The .txt files were saved by converting a python dictionary to a string and saving the string in a .txt file.

```
param_string = str(parameters-as-dict)
text_file = open(parameter_file_path, "w")
text_file.write(param_string)
text_file.close()
```

The entries of the dict are of mixed types (float, int, string,...). In some of the files one entry of the dict is a numpy-array and is saved in the txt-file as

```
'epsilons': array([...])
```

Because I want to access the values saved in the dict by their names, I now want to read the txt-file and load them as a dict again. This works easily with

```
f = open(path, 'r')
parameters = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

as long as there is no numpy array in the file. When the numpy-array is present, I get the error:

> File ".../python3.6/ast.py", line 84, in _convert
>       raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node)) ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7fb5428cc630>

Which makes sense, looking at the as.literal_eval documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) which says

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or
>   node provided may only consist of the following Python literal
>   **structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and
>   None.**

Since I can't resave the file differently, I don't know at which position the array is and I want to avoid cumbersome regex parsing, I'm searching for a solution that transforms my txt-file into a dict containing a numpy-array.

**EDIT:** the problem is not only the numpy array but also when I saved an object of e.g. a specific class:

```
 , 'foo' : <class bar>,
```

A solution, where everything that can not be parsed as some kind of number/bool/some knonw datatype is automatically saved as a string just as it is would satisfy my needs.

Comment: have you checked out the numpy methods for reading data from text files. there is quite the array of options there and this might easily solve your problem. I#m not to familiar myself with numpy though. have you also tried this : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html. that should work together with a try: and except: solution.

Comment: I'd edit the file (or read string) to remove the 'array' word.  Then the array should load as a list.

Comment: Another option would be an iterative approach with `try/except` catching those `ValueError` and handling them appropriately, i.e., `paramters['epsilons']= array([1,2,3])` should work.

Comment: @DavidZemens I think this approach merits being in an answer of it's own

Comment: What do you expect to get in return from `<class bar>`? An *instance*, of the class, or the class itself?

Comment: @DavidZemens I would be happy with a string '<class bar>'

Comment: @MTTI OK! I added an answer to that effect. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an iterative approach handling the exceptions as needed. I don't like using `eval`, perhaps there's a better way but this is quick and dirty and assumes you have safe inputs.

```
parameters = {}    
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(':')
        if val[:6] == '<class'
            # string representation like '<class bar>'
            # ast.literal_eval() can't handle this, and neither can eval()
            # this is just a string literal, so keep it as such:
            parameters[key] = val  
            continue
        try:
            parameters[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)
        except ValueError as e:
            # for unsupported data structures like np.array
            parameters[key] = eval(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to check for an array line by line. A quick & dirty suggestion:

```
parameters = {}    
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split(':')
       if 'array' in val:
           s = val.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0]
           parameters[key] = np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))
       else:
           parameters[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)
```

Maybe for future reference, you can try using the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to save your data.